# what do I use topic to measure kinect distance?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to know distance.

Documentation states that

depth/image_raw (sensor_msgs/Image)
Raw image from device. Contains uint16 depths in mm.

But I get is values one byte long, max of 255

What do I use topic to measure kinect distance?

How can I find depth?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41614/what-do-i-use-topic-to-measure-kinect-distance?/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to deserialize the message first (using [cv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge)). This will give you a cv::Mat containing uint16 values.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-16**:
how can I get the 11bit data?? can i use the way too? 16bit > 11bit  Is it right?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-08-16**:
What 11 bit data do you mean? The openni_camera wiki page doesn't say that anything coming from the kinect is 11 bit.

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-16**:
disparity's range is 0~2047. So I think i need 11bit data. Is it wrong?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-08-16**:
Just took a look at a disparity image coming from a kinect - the image claims its data is 32FC1 (single channel 32 bit float), so I guess it's just using a wider type than it needs. cv_bridge shouldn't have any trouble deserializing it.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
It has probably already been converted to meters, as well.

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-16**:
It has already been convert. What mean? "It" has been converted to meters. It is disparity or using cv_bridge? how cv_bridge make 8bit->16bit ? what principle?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
REP-0118 explains how it works: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-16**:
can you help me? I don't solve the problem. http://answers.ros.org/question/41252/i-find-kinect-depth-fomula-is-it-right-modified-question/